# ¿Qué significa este símbolo cuando hago un curl -s a una página web?

Tags: bash

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto y a la hora de hacer un curl -s a una página web y guardar su valor en un archivo me aparecen estos caracteres. ¿Alguien sabe lo que significan o por qué salen?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy realizando el código en bash

Este es el comando ejecutado

```
curl -s es-es.facebook.com | html2text > ut.tmp
```

Comment: Lo más extraño para mi es que aparezca en algunos puntos cadenas "normales" sin esos caracteres intercalados. ¿Podrías poner la URL de la que descargas ese texto, para poder examinar los códigos recibidos? ¿No has usado ninguna otra opción en `curl` aparte de `-s`?

Comment: Parece ser que hay un problema de codificación. Agrega a la pregunta el comando completo que está produciendo esa salida. Generalmente si indicas codificación utf8 este problema debería desaparecer.

Comment: curl -s https://es-es.facebook.com/ | html2text > ut.tmp. Ese es el comando ejecutado. No se si el problema puede ser el html2text.